# Attempting to reverse divs for responsive design

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am new to responsive design.

I have 4 floating left `div`s. but what I want to do is reverse the `div`s so that will look more responsive.

So the page currently displays

**FirstSecondThirdFourth**

What I want is:

**FourthThirdSecondFirst**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksaluja/L2chp56z/)

```css
#block-1,
#block-2,
#block-3 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <div id="block-1">First</div>
  <div id="block-2">Second</div>
  <div id="block-3">Third</div>
  <div id="block-4">Fourth</div>

</div>
```

Comment: what you mean by: *I want to do is reverse the divs so that the look will be more responsive.*

Comment: Good point. I have updated the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse`  and `justify-content:flex-end` (this is optional given what you want to do)

```css
#example {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content:flex-end  
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <div id="block-1">First</div>
  <div id="block-2">Second</div>
  <div id="block-3">Third</div>
  <div id="block-4">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to get it work floating right, but your solution is so much more elegant. Have a great day!